# Express proxy + axios + cors: still cors issue

Tags: node.js, express, proxy, cors

I've created the following proxy with express:

```
import express from "express";
import cors from "cors";
import proxy from "express-http-proxy";

const app = express();

app.use(
  cors({
     origin: "http://localhost:8081",
     credentials: true,
  })
);

app.use("/", proxy("http://my-website:8810"));
app.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log("server listening on port 3000");
});
```

From the frontend I'm using axios:

```
axios.defaults.withCredentials = true;
const res = await axios.get("http://localhost:3000", {
    auth: {
      username: "xxxxx",
      password: "xxxxx",
    },
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
    },
});
```

But I still have the following cors issue:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://my-website:8810' (redirected from
>   'http://localhost:3000/') from origin 'http://localhost:8081' has been
>   blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass
>   access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is
>   present on the requested resource.

And after many hours facing this issue... here I am. 
Could anyone explain to me what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score -1):

Finally it works by using "request", something like:

```
app.use(
  cors({
     origin: "http://localhost:8081",
     credentials: true,
  })
);

router.get("/", (req, res) => {  
  request(
    "http://my-website:8810",
    {
      auth: {
      username: "node_proxy",
      password: "password",
    },
    headers: { Accept: "application/json" },
    },
    (error, response, body) => {      
      res.send(body);
    }
  );
});
```